# Guardar un txt dentro de mi solucion

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Hola espero y puedan ayudarme.

Tengo este código

```
using(StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Prueba.txt"))
{
    escritor.WriteLine("Hola");
}
```

El problema es que cuando lo subo a mi host no guarda el archivo por la ruta y quisiera que el archivo se guardase dentro de mi solución y no en "C"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí les dejo la solución

```
using(StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/Prueba.txt"), true))
{
       escritor.WriteLine("Hola");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que usar la clase Server

```
Server.MapPath("Nombre de la carpeta dentro de tu proyecto")+ "\\" + NombreArchivo
```

Con esto va y busca a nivel del proyecto.

Comment: Gracias busque como aplicar esta solución y funciono abajo compartiré mi solución.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una ruta relativa a la raíz de tu proyecto como se explica en la [documentación de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178116(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Puedes utilizar el operador ~ junto con carpetas para especificar una
>   ruta de acceso que esté basada en la raíz actual.

---

```
using(StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter("~\Prueba.txt"))
{
    escritor.WriteLine("Hola");
}
```

Comment: Me sale este error System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\Prueba.txt'.'

Comment: Olvide quitar el `@` XD, ahora ya deberia funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así a ver que tal:

```
using (StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\Prueba.txt"))
{
    escritor.WriteLine("Hola");
}
```

Comment: Me muestra este error System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso 'C:\Prueba.txt'

Comment: No entiendo amigo quieres guardarlo en el disco o en tu solución porque la excepción te esta indicando que deseas guardarlo en el disco.

Comment: Puedes probar asi tambien: 
StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(@"..\Prueba.txt")

Comment: Ya encontré una solución pero respondiendo a tu pregunta quería guardar en mi solución pero el error salia ya que esa dirección como me la diste busca dentro de "C"